# How to copy sdf file from resources to Temporary Folder C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I have a windows form application in C#. In this `.resx` file, I have added an `.sdf` file (SQL Server CE database file) named `Database1.sdf` which contains empty tables. How can I copy the `.sdf` file from the resources to the temporary folder? I have tried `File.Copy` method, does not seem to work.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy it like this.

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"YourPath", Resources.Database1.sdf);
```

Comment: Tried
`File.WriteAllBytes(@"Path",ProjectName.Properties.Resources.Database1.sdf)`
Does not work

Comment: It is showing: `ProjectName.Properties.Resources does not contain a definition for 'Database1.sdf'`

Comment: You need `using System.IO;` for `File` and the Namespace for the Database is like `using YourProjectname.Properties;`

Comment: It looks like, I can't access any file in the resource not even a text file.